# Android - Google Analytics V4 Exception

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-firebase

So, I followed this ( http://java.dzone.com/articles/working-google-analytics-api ) tutorial to add Google Analytics v4 to my application but after everything that is there when I try to run it i get an error that looks like this:

```
09-13 12:52:01.122  31624-31624/com.rivert.unlockscope E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.rivert.unlockscope, PID: 31624
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rivert.unlockscope/com.rivert.unlockscope.unlockscope}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.rivert.unlockscope.MyApplication
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2187)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.rivert.unlockscope.MyApplication
        at com.rivert.unlockscope.unlockscope.onCreate(unlockscope.java:37)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5241)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        09-13 12:52:02.594  31624-31624/com.rivert.unlockscope I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 31624 SIG: 9
```

My code from line 37 is:

`((MyApplication) getApplication()).getTracker(MyApplication.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);`

Can anyone help me? Thanks

LE:

MyApplication Code

```
package com.rivert.unlockscope;

import android.app.Application;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by Coman Alexandru on 12/09/2014.
 */
public class MyApplication extends Application {

// The following line should be changed to include the correct property id.
private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-XXXXXXXX-X";

//Logging TAG
private static final String TAG = "TestName";

public static int GENERAL_TRACKER = 0;

public enum TrackerName {
    APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
    GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
    ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a company.
}

HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

public MyApplication() {
    super();
}

synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker)
                : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
                : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
        mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

    }
    return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
}

}
```

MY LOG:

http://pastebin.com/a2iidewj

Comment: Can I see the code for MyApplication?

Comment: Well, you can find it in the tutorial posted in the first paragraph.

Comment: The thing is the tutorial is most likely correct. When you follow the tutorials you make unwanted mistakes sometimes. Therefore, your code is more important for me when I try to solve your issue. Some checks, have you declared your MyApplication class in your manifest? Is your MyApplication Class extending android.app.Application?

Comment: No. I MyApplication class is not declared in AndroidManifest :(. I couldn't find anything saying thins in the tutorial. I thought only activities should be declared in AndroidManifest.

Comment: Did that fix your problem?

Comment: It's not an Activity, how can I declare it?

Comment: Have a look at class explanation in here (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

Comment: Something like here (https://github.com/hoomi/Restaurant_Finder/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: It fixed my issue but my analytics code doesn't work. I put my log above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61198/discussion-between-iceman2hot4u-and-hoomi).

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue before. You need to add Application name in manifest file.

```
 <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainApplication" >
 </application>
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you have to set your android:name to the class you created that extends application. For example, if your class is:

```
public class Thisnameinmanifestconfig extends Application{
    private Tracker mTracker;
    synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
        if(mTracker == null){
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
    }
    return mTracker;
}
```

Your manifest should be:

```
<application
    android:name=".Thisnameinmanifestconfig"
    .../>
</application>
```

That's it. I hope it helps.